# How to store text in a database without having a duplicate and words order doesn't matter?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I want to store searches on my site in a database and I want them to be unique even though the order of words doesn't matter for me for example:

```
some words
```

and

```
words some
```

are the same for me, and I just want to update the time of the last search.

So is there a way to do this in SQL (like UNIQUE) or should I find a solution in a server side language ?

And thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just split the search, store words in a database, create a search table, and have a join table in the middle. Probably somewhat easier in Rails, than PHP. Not use about ASP/C#.

Comment: Also, really work out if it is that big of a requirement that this happens. I can see you wanting to do this as some kind of scaling thing, or space saving thing. If it's space saving, and you don't have 10 million users, don't bother. If it's scaling, there is going to be no way more effective than putting all searches in a table and uniquing them. Joins and all the other methods you would use would put more strain on the server. Basically... don't do it unless you have millions of users and shaving space... especially on searches??... is an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way to do this, but the only way I can think is that in PHP you split the string by spaces and then order it alphabetically:

```
$words = explode(" ", $keywords);
sort($words);
$sorted_keywords = implode(" ", $words);
```

Then when you store/search from database you'll always be using the same string no matter which order the words WERE in.

Answer (score 1):

```
$words = preg_split("\b", $words);
sort($words);
implode(" ", $words);
```

You can also just explode on a space if you're definitely separating words by spaces and you can use `array_unique` as well.  This will be a sorted string listed the searched words.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt if DBMS provides such a facility out of the box. You would need to normalize your search text in such a way that

```
normalize("some words") = normalize("words some")
```

and then you can store the normalized version in your database and update it whenever a different search text resulting in the same normalized form is encountered.